# Use case for Mule CRC32 Processor

Tags: mule

I have been trying to figure out under what use cases the [CRC32 Processo](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+CRC32+Processor)r might be used ...

The example in the documentation looks at the Payload but my guess is that in most cases the payload is going to change from when the message entered into the flow versus when it will exit from the flow ...

Which part of the message would be the same from start to finish to allow the CRC's to match ? ...

An example of when to use it would be great ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the documentation extremely confusing too, especially when it says:

> The CRC32 processor acts as an enricher to generate a checksum to a
>   message when it enters a system, then act as a filter to verify the
>   checksum when the message leaves the system.

Being an EE feature, I can't locate integration tests for it, which could have shed some light on the intent of this filter.

Personally, my take on it is:

- Use it to calculate and verify the CRC32 of inbound messages,
- Use it to generate a CRC32 and attach it to outbound messages.

Comment: "Use it to calculate and verify the CRC32 of inbound messages" .. by this you mean that the inbound message should already have a CRC32 attached with it (calculated from external source) and then the flow does the calculation again and tried to match the values ? ...

Comment: Yes, correct. It could be provided in a meta field, like an HTTP header or a JMS property.